# Does windows 7 supports docker daemon?

Tags: docker

I have installed docker toolbox on windows 7. Every thing works well including docker-compose,docker-machine except docker daemon.

**My docker version :**

```
client:
  version:1.11.1
  API version:1.23
  os/Arch:windows/amd64

server:
  version:1.12.1
  API version: 1.24
  os/Arch: linux/amd64
```

When i execute `docker daemon` command, it throws this error

> time="2016-9-08T14:39:53.685141700+05:30" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon : The version of windows does not support the docker daemon"

When i give `dockerd`, it throws

> bash: dockerd: command not found

Is there any steps to make it work? or windows 7 does not support?

Comment: I'd say the error message should have answered your question.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-dev/td6DYjQevEg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Native Windows containers are still in development and I don't believe Windows 7 will be included in that supported list, Windows Server 2016 is being targeted. With Windows 7, Docker runs as a Linux VM under the covers.

Comment: Microsoft will soon release daemon support for Windows Server 2016, and Windows 10 may follow.   WinDocks provides support for Windows 8, Windows 10, Server 2012 and 2016.

Answer (score 0):

From [Docker website](https://www.docker.com/products/docker#/windows)

> **DOCKER FOR WINDOWS**
>
> [...]
>
> **Requires Microsoft Windows 10 Professional or Enterprise 64-bit**
>   For previous versions get [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox)

### EDIT

**Docker containers can't run directly on Windows (10 or 7)**. It required virtualization system in all cases.

On Windows 7, you need Oracle Virtual Box which is included in Docker Toolbox.

On Windows 10, [Hyper-V](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/mt169373(v=ws.11).aspx) replaces Oracle Virtual Box.

Comment: That's "Docker for Windows" which still uses hyper-V to run a Linux OS. Docker toolbox runs on 7 and includes Virtualbox for the Linux OS. https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

Comment: My bad. I just read documentation about Hyper-V. I didn't know it was a vitualization system for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to excecute your commands into **Docker Quickstart Terminal**. I'm using a command that needs docker daemon and worked.